# How to install Craft 3 on shared hosting

Tags: craft3, installation, hosting

I would like to learn Craft 3 CMS.

I would like to do so by installing it manually on shared hosting. I am not familiar with Composer and would like to learn Craft before committing to learning Composer.

I do not understand some of the steps given at:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html

So I searched for manual installation of Craft 3 on shared hosting on the net and did not find any helpful articles. Examples on the net are based on using Composer or Craft 2 or using a local dev environment, etc.

So I have come here hoping that some people will help me out with the steps I don't understand at:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html

Here we go:

> Extract the archive wherever you want your new Craft project to
>   live.

In my case my shared hosting provides me with the following directory structure:

/home/[accountname]/public_html

I am used to developing with Wordpress and if I use shared hosting I will simply put all of WP in a folder named the same as the domain, eg:

/home/[accountname]/public_html/example.com

So I am not sure where I should upload the Craft files to, also because of the next step below.

> Directory Structure
>
> Once Craft’s files are in place, your project directory should have a
>   directory structure like this:
>
> ```
> my-project.test/
> ├── config/
> │   └── ...
> ├── storage/
> │   └── ...
> ├── templates/
> │   └── ...
> ├── vendor/
> │   └── ...
> ├── web/
> │   └── ...
> ├── .env
> ├── .env.example
> ├── composer.json
> ├── craft
> └── craft.bat
> ```
>
> TIP
>
> The web/ folder represents your site’s webroot, and it can be renamed
>   to whatever you want (www/, public/, public_html/, etc.). "

If I were to install these files in eg:

/home/[accountname]/public_html/my-project.test/

Then this becomes confusing to me because I once managed to install Craft 2 on shared hosting and Craft 2 installation instructions made it clear that I had to install most of Craft 2 above the webroot:

/home/[accountname]/craft/

And I had the craft webroot at
/home/[accountname]/public_html/craftsite/

But if I upload craft to:

/home/[accountname]/public_html/my-project.test/

Then obviously all of Craft is under not above the webroot. I imagine this could be very insecure....

But the Craft 3 instructions do not mention that I need to install some folders above the webroot.

I also feel I have 2 webroots now:

My shared hosting tells me that I have a webroot at:
/home/[accountname]/public_html/

While Craft is saying my webroot is:
/home/[accountname]/public_html/my-project.test/web/

Maybe I need to install Craft 3 above the webroot, eg:

/home/[accountname]/my-project.test/

And then the Craft webroot would be:

/home/[accountname]/my-project.test/web/

But I also have a webroot at:

/home/[accountname]/public_html/

So now I also have 2 webroots....

> Step 5: Set up the Web Server
>
> Create a new web server to host your Craft project. Its document root
>   (or “webroot”) should point to your web/ directory (or whatever you’ve
>   renamed it to).

I my case I dont believe I can create a web server - I am stuck with the shared hosting server.

So I am not sure how to handle this step.

I am sorry if I am missing some very obvious things here.....

Any help would be very much appreciated.....

Comment: Try to upload all the files except the `web` folder above your `public_html`. Once that's done, upload **the content** of the `web` folder (`index.php` and `.htaccess`, not the folder itself) in your `public_html`.

Comment: Thanks very much Oli I will try that.

Comment: My only other question then becomes - If I upload all the files above public_html except web folder, and I have more than one Craft site, can I use those same folders above public_html for multiple Craft sites? In other words can they be shared across Craft sites?

Comment: It depends on your definition of multiple sites. If they are unrelated websites, for different clients then you would have separate hosting and therefore separate Craft installs for each website. Craft does support multi-sites but that is for a single company that has multiple related websites. For instance a company could have two main products and each product has its own domain and website but both are edited by the same team. In which case you can use the Sites facility and all sites would then use the same Craft install.

Comment: JollyR a belated thanks. My sites would be independent. In the meantime I have asked my hosting company and they cleared it up for me.